# Reaching computers on second computers lan though network router

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

Using Linux.

Main computer ethernet adaptor eth0, ip 192.168.2.5 connected to router, ip 192.168.2.1 router connected to cable modem.

Second computer ethernet adapter#1 eth0, ip 192.168.2.10 connected to router, has access to internet. Second computers ethernet adapter#2 eth1, ip 192.168.3.1 connected to a network hub.

Two raspberry pis connected via usb->ethernet adapter to network hub.  ips 192.168.3.20 & 192.168.3.21 everything on 192.168.3.* reaches each other.

I want to reach rpi @ 192.168.3.20 from first computer 192.168.2.5.  What do I need to do on computer 1 & 2? I'm fine with using ip's vs nameserver.

[block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZylnA.jpg)

Comment: Could you perhaps draw a topology of the network? It's hard to say what device should be forwarding traffic to which direction when you don't know how exactly they're connected. Thanks :-) Please note down also what interface has which IP address.

Comment: home use.  Main router is a regular 2/5Gz wireless router.  2nd is a 1MB 8-port hub.  Don't have long enough cables to connect pis to router, even though I don't need this as a permanent solution, I'm trying to debug program on more powerful main computer.

Comment: you need to configure the "second computer" as a router (preferably without NAT). look up how to do that for your particular distro of linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the router to route packets bound for `192.168.3.0/24` to `192.168.2.10`. That should be it.

The only problem you currently have occurs when machines in the 192.168.2.0/24 network (other than the one with the connection to to the 192.168.3.0/24 network) try to send packets to machines on the 192.168.3.0/24 network. These machines have no route to 192.168.3.0/24, so they will send the packets along their default route, to the router. But the router has no idea that the 192.168.3.0/24 network is connected to 192.168.2.10 -- so it needs an additional route.

Everything else should "just work" unless you have something unusual in your setup.